# What is the simplest way to get a video stream from a webcam as H.264?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

The main requirement is that it is H.264 encoded video. I would prefer simpler solutions, even hacks, if the overhead is not excessively large (say ≥ 30ms). I don't want to use a framework that reads and decodes H.264 streams for me, because I need access to the encoded H.264 video data. These are my thoughts so far:

- I've considered using ffmpeg as encoder and reading in the stream via UDP, but depacketizing and handling dropped packages might require some work.
- Perhaps I could write the video stream to memory using *tmpfs*, however I want to be platform agnostic between Windows and Linux.
- ffmpeg also has an option to write to a file to *stdout*, which however is line-based, so that might not be well suited for video data. I've read that there are ways to disable line-buffering when piping standard outputs, but I am not sure how reliable that is.
- Another idea is to launch ffmpeg as a subprocess and access the output more directly in the RAM or perhaps continuously from the standard output without line-buffers (if that is possible).
- Yet another option might be using libx264 directly, but that seems to be be more work than reading ffmpeg via UDP.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have a webcam, connected to PC, and you want to read its output in realtime as h246? You can use FFmpeg to send the stream to a socket, and there will be no extra buffering on FFmpeg side.

Comment: Do you mean a UDP socket? Then my question is whether there are simpler ways to read in the stream apart from using sockets.

Comment: When we speak about local socket, UDP vs TCP does not really matter. If you don't need to *stream* the video, but rather pass the encoded frames for some processing, you can write your code that will be calling libavcodec and continue with whatever custom logic you need.

Comment: My question is whether that is likely more or less work than reading the stream by depacketizing UDP? By the way, code that reads H.264 from a file is already implemented. (ffmpeg is convenient because it already takes care of talking to the webcam.)

Comment: FFmpeg is open source, so whatever it does to talk to webcam is done by the same libraries (e.g. avdevice) that you can use in your code.

Comment: Using these libraries directly and manually configuring all the parameters seems to be a lot more work than implementing a UDP H.264 stream reader. I've done neither before, so that's why I am asking.

Comment: That's your choice. Whether you want better control, or rely on IPC.

Comment: What would you say is less work to do? I find the amount of control provided by ffmpeg sufficient.